# Absolute Convergence of a Function

Tags: measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have got stuck with a question. Please help me.
Prove that $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ belongs to $L^p$ for all $p>1$.
Thank You.

Comment: Use that $\sin x / x$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and $1/x$ is in $\mathbb L^p([1, \infty))$ for all $p > 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^p=1$$
then the integral
$$\int_0^1\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|^p dx\quad \forall p$$
is convergent, moreover we have
$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|^p\leq\frac{1}{x^p} $$
and since the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p}\quad\text{is convergent if}\quad p>1$$
then we can conclude that $x\mapsto\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ belongs to $L^p$ for all $p>1$.

Comment: Excellent, my friend!